# Extracting the substring between 2 substrings

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed, grep

In Bash I have a variable that contains a JSON object as string, for example:

`{"results":[{"Name":"blah-1","Version":"1.0"},{"Name":"Some Other Name","Version":"2b-alpha"}]}`

I got this from a call to `curl`.

I want go get the version strings into a bash array, such that when I call `printf '%s\n' "${versions[@]}"` it prints each version string line by line:

```
1.0
2b-alpha
```

There can be an arbitrary amount of occurences of these Version strings in the JSON. How would I do this, can it be done with pure bash or would I need `grep` or `sed` and what would the command look like?

Comment: If you want to parse json, use a json parser. If you think about it for long enough, you'll realize it's logical and makes sense.

Comment: Use `jq` to parse `json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`gniourf-gniourf`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) suggests, use an appropriate `JSON` parser like `jq` for parsing, for better maintainability. Do something like

```
$ echo "$jsonString" | jq -r '.results[] | "\(.Version)"'
```

which should print the contents as

```
1.0
2b-alpha
```

The idea is the `jq` filter `.results[] | "\(.Version)"` selects all nodes under result and extracts all the names of `Version` under it.

To store it to an array use [process-substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) as,

```
read -r -a jsonArray < <(echo "$jsonString" | jq -r '.results[] | "\(.Version)"')
```

and print the array contents as

```
printf '%s\n' "${jsonArray[@]}"
```

Refer [GitHub-jq-documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) page for download instructions.

Comment: You can use `.results[].Version`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the version numbers, you don't need to store the result from curl in a variable. You can directly pipe the results from curl into jq:

```
versions=($(curl 'http://server/path' | jq -r '.results[].Version'))
```

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
arr=($(echo "$x" | grep -oP '(?<="Version":")[^"]+' ))
```

where `x` is the variable in which your string is stored.

`o` - to extract only part of string
`P` - to use perl-like regex, we are using postive look behind

You can access it like:

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```